# replace function with dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I want to build a dictionary or something for the replace function to look
up and replace each string throughout an entire column respectively. For example if the replace function finds the characters 'Drive', 'Dr', 
'DRIVE', or 'Dr.', I would like all of those to be replaced by 'DR' and all the other street endings.

current

```
Address
'123 Alabama Drive',
'12 Florida Str',
'10 10th Dr.'
```

replaced with

```
'123 ALABAMA DR',
'12 FLORIDA ST',
'10 10TH DR'
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: is this possible, if so how?

Comment: There are plenty of examples on line showing how to set up a dictionary for value correspondence.  How do these not give you enough of a starting point to write any code?

Answer (score 4):

See [this function](http://bcdcspatial.blogspot.com/2012/09/normalize-to-usps-street-abbreviations.html) for starting point. As MShaw notes, left unmodified, it will return some undesired results in cases like `'123 portland port`, as it would abbreviate to `'123 prtland prt'`, etc.

```
def normalizeStreetSuffixes(inputValue,case='u'):
        '''
        if case=='l', returns lowercase
        if case=='u', returns uppercase
        else returns proper case
        '''
        case = case[0].lower()
        abbv = suffixDict()
        words = inputValue.split()
        for i,word in enumerate(words):
            w = word.lower()
            rep = abbv[w] if w in abbv.keys() else words[i]
            words[i] = rep.upper() if case == 'u' else rep.lower() if case == 'l' else (rep[0].upper() + rep[1:])
        return ' '.join(words)

def suffixDict():
    """
    Use common abbreviations -> USPS standardized abbreviation to replace common street suffixes

    Obtains list from https://www.usps.com/send/official-abbreviations.htm
    """
    return {'trpk': 'tpke', 'forges': 'frgs', 'bypas': 'byp', 'mnr': 'mnr', 'viaduct': 'via', 'mnt': 'mt',
            'lndng': 'lndg', 'vill': 'vlg', 'aly': 'aly', 'mill': 'ml', 'pts': 'pts', 'centers': 'ctrs', 'row': 'row', 'cnter': 'ctr',
            'hrbor': 'hbr', 'tr': 'trl', 'lndg': 'lndg', 'passage': 'psge', 'walks': 'walk', 'frks': 'frks', 'crest': 'crst', 'meadows': 'mdws',
            'freewy': 'fwy', 'garden': 'gdn', 'bluffs': 'blfs', 'vlg': 'vlg', 'vly': 'vly', 'fall': 'fall', 'trk': 'trak', 'squares': 'sqs',
            'trl': 'trl', 'harbor': 'hbr', 'frry': 'fry', 'div': 'dv', 'straven': 'stra', 'cmp': 'cp', 'grdns': 'gdns', 'villg': 'vlg',
            'meadow': 'mdw', 'trails': 'trl', 'streets': 'sts', 'prairie': 'pr', 'hts': 'hts', 'crescent': 'cres', 'pass': 'pass',
            'ter': 'ter', 'port': 'prt', 'bluf': 'blf', 'avnue': 'ave', 'lights': 'lgts', 'rpds': 'rpds', 'harbors': 'hbrs',
            'mews': 'mews', 'lodg': 'ldg', 'plz': 'plz', 'tracks': 'trak', 'path': 'path', 'pkway': 'pkwy', 'gln': 'gln',
            'bot': 'btm', 'drv': 'dr', 'rdg': 'rdg', 'fwy': 'fwy', 'hbr': 'hbr', 'via': 'via', 'divide': 'dv', 'inlt': 'inlt',
            'fords': 'frds', 'avenu': 'ave', 'vis': 'vis', 'brk': 'brk', 'rivr': 'riv', 'oval': 'oval', 'gateway': 'gtwy',
            'stream': 'strm', 'bayoo': 'byu', 'msn': 'msn', 'knoll': 'knl', 'expressway': 'expy', 'sprng': 'spg',
            'flat': 'flt', 'holw': 'holw', 'grden': 'gdn', 'trail': 'trl', 'jctns': 'jcts', 'rdgs': 'rdgs',
            'tunnel': 'tunl', 'ml': 'ml', 'fls': 'fls', 'flt': 'flt', 'lks': 'lks', 'mt': 'mt', 'groves': 'grvs',
            'vally': 'vly', 'ferry': 'fry', 'parkway': 'pkwy', 'radiel': 'radl', 'strvnue': 'stra', 'fld': 'fld',
            'overpass': 'opas', 'plaza': 'plz', 'estate': 'est', 'mntn': 'mtn', 'lock': 'lck', 'orchrd': 'orch',
            'strvn': 'stra', 'locks': 'lcks', 'bend': 'bnd', 'kys': 'kys', 'junctions': 'jcts', 'mountin': 'mtn',
            'burgs': 'bgs', 'pine': 'pne', 'ldge': 'ldg', 'causway': 'cswy', 'spg': 'spg', 'beach': 'bch', 'ft': 'ft',
            'crse': 'crse', 'motorway': 'mtwy', 'bluff': 'blf', 'court': 'ct', 'grov': 'grv', 'sprngs': 'spgs',
            'ovl': 'oval', 'villag': 'vlg', 'vdct': 'via', 'neck': 'nck', 'orchard': 'orch', 'light': 'lgt',
            'sq': 'sq', 'pkwy': 'pkwy', 'shore': 'shr', 'green': 'grn', 'strm': 'strm', 'islnd': 'is',
            'turnpike': 'tpke', 'stra': 'stra', 'mission': 'msn', 'spngs': 'spgs', 'course': 'crse',
            'trafficway': 'trfy', 'terrace': 'ter', 'hway': 'hwy', 'avenue': 'ave', 'glen': 'gln',
            'boul': 'blvd', 'inlet': 'inlt', 'la': 'ln', 'ln': 'ln', 'frst': 'frst', 'clf': 'clf',
            'cres': 'cres', 'brook': 'brk', 'lk': 'lk', 'byp': 'byp', 'shoar': 'shr', 'bypass': 'byp',
            'mtin': 'mtn', 'ally': 'aly', 'forest': 'frst', 'junction': 'jct', 'views': 'vws', 'wells': 'wls', 'cen': 'ctr',
            'exts': 'exts', 'crt': 'ct', 'corners': 'cors', 'trak': 'trak', 'frway': 'fwy', 'prarie': 'pr', 'crossing': 'xing',
            'extn': 'ext', 'cliffs': 'clfs', 'manors': 'mnrs', 'ports': 'prts', 'gatewy': 'gtwy', 'square': 'sq', 'hls': 'hls',
            'harb': 'hbr', 'loops': 'loop', 'mdw': 'mdw', 'smt': 'smt', 'rd': 'rd', 'hill': 'hl', 'blf': 'blf',
            'highway': 'hwy', 'walk': 'walk', 'clfs': 'clfs', 'brooks': 'brks', 'brnch': 'br', 'aven': 'ave',
            'shores': 'shrs', 'iss': 'iss', 'route': 'rte', 'wls': 'wls', 'place': 'pl', 'sumit': 'smt', 'pines': 'pnes',
            'trks': 'trak', 'shoal': 'shl', 'strt': 'st', 'frwy': 'fwy', 'heights': 'hts', 'ranches': 'rnch',
            'boulevard': 'blvd', 'extnsn': 'ext', 'mdws': 'mdws', 'hollows': 'holw', 'vsta': 'vis', 'plains': 'plns',
            'station': 'sta', 'circl': 'cir', 'mntns': 'mtns', 'prts': 'prts', 'shls': 'shls', 'villages': 'vlgs',
            'park': 'park', 'nck': 'nck', 'rst': 'rst', 'haven': 'hvn', 'turnpk': 'tpke', 'expy': 'expy', 'sta': 'sta',
            'expr': 'expy', 'stn': 'sta', 'expw': 'expy', 'street': 'st', 'str': 'st', 'spurs': 'spur', 'crecent': 'cres',
            'rad': 'radl', 'ranch': 'rnch', 'well': 'wl', 'shoals': 'shls', 'alley': 'aly', 'plza': 'plz', 'medows': 'mdws',
            'allee': 'aly', 'knls': 'knls', 'ests': 'ests', 'st': 'st', 'anx': 'anx', 'havn': 'hvn', 'paths': 'path', 'bypa': 'byp',
            'spgs': 'spgs', 'mills': 'mls', 'parks': 'park', 'byps': 'byp', 'flts': 'flts', 'tunnels': 'tunl', 'club': 'clb', 'sqrs': 'sqs',
            'hllw': 'holw', 'manor': 'mnr', 'centre': 'ctr', 'track': 'trak', 'hgts': 'hts', 'rnch': 'rnch', 'crcle': 'cir', 'falls': 'fls',
            'landing': 'lndg', 'plaines': 'plns', 'viadct': 'via', 'gdns': 'gdns', 'gtwy': 'gtwy', 'grove': 'grv', 'camp': 'cp', 'tpk': 'tpke',
            'drive': 'dr', 'freeway': 'fwy', 'ext': 'ext', 'points': 'pts', 'exp': 'expy', 'ky': 'ky', 'courts': 'cts', 'pky': 'pkwy', 'corner': 'cor',
            'crssing': 'xing', 'mnrs': 'mnrs', 'unions': 'uns', 'cyn': 'cyn', 'lodge': 'ldg', 'trfy': 'trfy', 'circle': 'cir', 'bridge': 'brg',
            'dl': 'dl', 'dm': 'dm', 'express': 'expy', 'tunls': 'tunl', 'dv': 'dv', 'dr': 'dr', 'shr': 'shr', 'knolls': 'knls', 'greens': 'grns',
            'tunel': 'tunl', 'fields': 'flds', 'common': 'cmn', 'orch': 'orch', 'crk': 'crk', 'river': 'riv', 'shl': 'shl', 'view': 'vw',
            'crsent': 'cres', 'rnchs': 'rnch', 'crscnt': 'cres', 'arc': 'arc', 'btm': 'btm', 'blvd': 'blvd', 'ways': 'ways', 'radl': 'radl',
            'rdge': 'rdg', 'causeway': 'cswy', 'parkwy': 'pkwy', 'juncton': 'jct', 'statn': 'sta', 'gardn': 'gdn', 'mntain': 'mtn',
            'crssng': 'xing', 'rapid': 'rpd', 'key': 'ky', 'plns': 'plns', 'wy': 'way', 'cor': 'cor', 'ramp': 'ramp', 'throughway': 'trwy',
            'estates': 'ests', 'ck': 'crk', 'loaf': 'lf', 'hvn': 'hvn', 'wall': 'wall', 'hollow': 'holw', 'canyon': 'cyn', 'clb': 'clb',
            'cswy': 'cswy', 'village': 'vlg', 'cr': 'crk', 'trce': 'trce', 'cp': 'cp', 'cv': 'cv', 'ct': 'cts', 'pr': 'pr', 'frg': 'frg',
            'jction': 'jct', 'pt': 'pt', 'mssn': 'msn', 'frk': 'frk', 'brdge': 'brg', 'cent': 'ctr', 'spur': 'spur', 'frt': 'ft', 'pk': 'park',
            'fry': 'fry', 'pl': 'pl', 'lanes': 'ln', 'gtway': 'gtwy', 'prk': 'park', 'vws': 'vws', 'stravenue': 'stra', 'lgt': 'lgt',
            'hiway': 'hwy', 'ctr': 'ctr', 'prt': 'prt', 'ville': 'vl', 'plain': 'pln', 'mount': 'mt', 'mls': 'mls', 'loop': 'loop',
            'riv': 'riv', 'centr': 'ctr', 'is': 'is', 'prr': 'pr', 'vl': 'vl', 'avn': 'ave', 'vw': 'vw', 'ave': 'ave', 'spng': 'spg',
            'hiwy': 'hwy', 'dam': 'dm', 'isle': 'isle', 'crcl': 'cir', 'sqre': 'sq', 'jct': 'jct', 'jctn': 'jct', 'mountain': 'mtn',
            'keys': 'kys', 'parkways': 'pkwy', 'drives': 'drs', 'tunl': 'tunl', 'jcts': 'jcts', 'knl': 'knl', 'center': 'ctr',
            'driv': 'dr', 'tpke': 'tpke', 'sumitt': 'smt', 'canyn': 'cyn', 'ldg': 'ldg', 'harbr': 'hbr', 'rest': 'rst', 'shoars': 'shrs',
            'vist': 'vis', 'gdn': 'gdn', 'islnds': 'iss', 'hills': 'hls', 'cresent': 'cres', 'point': 'pt', 'lake': 'lk', 'vlly': 'vly',
            'strav': 'stra', 'crossroad': 'xrd', 'bnd': 'bnd', 'strave': 'stra', 'stravn': 'stra', 'knol': 'knl', 'vlgs': 'vlgs',
            'forge': 'frg', 'cntr': 'ctr', 'cape': 'cpe', 'height': 'hts', 'lck': 'lck', 'highwy': 'hwy', 'trnpk': 'tpke', 'rpd': 'rpd',
            'boulv': 'blvd', 'circles': 'cirs', 'valleys': 'vlys', 'vst': 'vis', 'creek': 'crk', 'mall': 'mall', 'spring': 'spg',
            'brg': 'brg', 'holws': 'holw', 'lf': 'lf', 'est': 'est', 'xing': 'xing', 'trace': 'trce', 'bottom': 'btm',
            'streme': 'strm', 'isles': 'isle', 'circ': 'cir', 'forks': 'frks', 'burg': 'bg', 'run': 'run', 'trls': 'trl',
            'radial': 'radl', 'lakes': 'lks', 'rue': 'rue', 'vlys': 'vlys', 'br': 'br', 'cors': 'cors', 'pln': 'pln',
            'pike': 'pike', 'extension': 'ext', 'island': 'is', 'frd': 'frd', 'lcks': 'lcks', 'terr': 'ter',
            'union': 'un', 'extensions': 'exts', 'pkwys': 'pkwy', 'islands': 'iss', 'road': 'rd', 'shrs': 'shrs',
            'roads': 'rds', 'glens': 'glns', 'springs': 'spgs', 'missn': 'msn', 'ridge': 'rdg', 'arcade': 'arc',
            'bayou': 'byu', 'crsnt': 'cres', 'junctn': 'jct', 'way': 'way', 'valley': 'vly', 'fork': 'frk',
            'mountains': 'mtns', 'bottm': 'btm', 'forg': 'frg', 'ht': 'hts', 'ford': 'frd', 'hl': 'hl',
            'grdn': 'gdn', 'fort': 'ft', 'traces': 'trce', 'cnyn': 'cyn', 'cir': 'cir', 'un': 'un', 'mtn': 'mtn',
            'flats': 'flts', 'anex': 'anx', 'gatway': 'gtwy', 'rapids': 'rpds', 'villiage': 'vlg', 'flds': 'flds',
            'coves': 'cvs', 'rvr': 'riv', 'av': 'ave', 'pikes': 'pike', 'grv': 'grv', 'vista': 'vis', 'pnes': 'pnes',
            'forests': 'frst', 'field': 'fld', 'branch': 'br', 'grn': 'grn', 'dale': 'dl', 'rds': 'rds', 'annex': 'anx',
            'sqr': 'sq', 'cove': 'cv', 'squ': 'sq', 'skyway': 'skwy', 'ridges': 'rdgs', 'hwy': 'hwy', 'tunnl': 'tunl',
            'underpass': 'upas', 'cliff': 'clf', 'lane': 'ln', 'land': 'land', 'bch': 'bch', 'dvd': 'dv', 'curve': 'curv',
            'cpe': 'cpe', 'summit': 'smt', 'gardens': 'gdns'}
```

Results:

```
>>> map(normalizeStreetSuffixes,adds)
['123 ALABAMA DR', '12 FLORIDA ST', '10 10TH DR.', '5638 PORTLAND PRT']

>>> map(normalizeStreetSuffixes,adds,repeat('l', len(adds)))
['123 alabama dr', '12 florida st', '10 10th dr.', '5638 portland prt']

>>> map(normalizeStreetSuffixes,adds,repeat('p', len(adds)))
['123 Alabama Dr', '12 Florida St', '10 10th Dr.', '5638 Portland Prt']
```

Comment: Might want to join the array of words before returning? `return ' '.join(inputValue)`

Comment: @M.Shaw shouldn't be necessary `inputValue` taken as a string and returned as a string.

Comment: Oh wait I thought you were replacing split words in the array. If you directly replace substrings in the original string, you might end up having `Portland Port`  becoming `PRTLAND PRT`, which is probably incorrect.

Comment: @M.Shaw nope, it's splitting the input string to list, then taking each word individiually.

Comment: You are replacing every occurrence of the key in the original string by the value in the mapping. See [this](http://ideone.com/ZNuj0s).

Comment: @M.Shaw yes I see that now. I am making some modifications to this function to replace wordsby index, rather than string replace.

Comment: @M.Shaw fixed this function and allowed for user option for upper/lowercase return value.

Comment: The source of abbreviations is outdated. I found it now at https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28apc_002.htm